# Show that $7$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have to show that $7$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[i]$.

To show irreducibility I have to show that it's not a unit. This is simple to just show exhaustively.

I'm having trouble with the second part which is to show that if it factors into $a.b$ that either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

What I have so far is that

$7 = (a + bi)(c + di)$

$7 = (ac - bd) + (ad + cb)i$

Which gives two linear equations

$ad+cb=0$

$ac-bd=7$

How do I get from that to a complete proof? Or have I gone down the wrong path.

Comment: Consider the map $N(a+bi) = a^2 + b^2$. It satisfies $N(z\cdot w) = N(z)\cdot N(w)$.

Comment: I am not sure whether ([tag:irreducible-polynomials]) is a good tag for this question. But I do not see any tag related directly to irreducible elements when I browse similar question, see for example some of the questions in [this search](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=irreducible+%22mathbb+Z[i]%22) and [this search](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=irreducible+%22mathbb+Z%22).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: First, show that $a+bi$ is a unit if and only if $|a+bi|^2=1$ (that is, if and only if $a^2+b^2=1$). Next, show that $a+bi\mapsto|a+bi|^2$ is a multiplicative function, meaning that $|(a+bi)(c+di)|^2=|a+bi|^2|c+di|^2.$ When $7=(a+bi)(c+di),$ what can we conclude about the possible values of $|a+bi|^2$ and $|c+di|^2$? What does that tell us about $7$?

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Thanks for your help!